# Decrypt RIJNDAEL-128 in Java

Tags: java, php, laravel, laravel-5, rijndael

I have encrypted text using Crypt function in Laravel. I am using cipher - MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 and CBC. How can I decrypt in Java? Here is the code of decryption in Laravel/PHP

```
$payload = json_encode(base64_decode($payload), true);
$value = base64_decode($payload['value']);
$iv = base64_decode($payload['iv']);
return unserialize($this->stripPadding($this->mcryptDecrypt($value, $iv)));

protected function mcryptDecrypt($value, $iv)
    {
        try
        {
            return mcrypt_decrypt($this->cipher, $this->key, $value, $this->mode, $iv);
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            throw new DecryptException($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does your original data look like? Is it meeting the contract of your code (ie. is it a Base 64-encoded JSON object containing Base 64-encoded value and IV that correspond to a serialized, padded data payload)?

Comment: Yes, it is a base64-encoded.
Here is the encryption data looks like : 
eyJpdiI6IjM5akZ2Zk1kZzdPeG5penNIdFpHY0E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoidHJQbzFzMjl4aFwvNEp4SWszMWlzeWc9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjFhMTMzNWE2NWM2ZTA1NDA2N2Q3OGNiNmY3NWNmNTJlMTBlYzZiN2JkMGZmOTVlNGU5Y2M1N2JmZmQxYWI3MzQifQ==

Comment: @ShotgunNinja can you please help me here?